# Reported speech question

Tags: dialogue, indirect-speech

What would be the indirect speech form of the following sentence?

> **John told Sean, "Let me help you"**

(It's not a homework question, I'm preparing for my exam tomorrow. I just stumbled upon this question in a book.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> John told Sean to let him help him.

I realise that creates ambiguity as to who was going to help who, but the context would probably sort it out.

Comment: That is probably the most elegant rendering, but it is strictly speaking not reported speech. Or is it? Perhaps we should agree on a definition first.

Comment: @Barrie: I agree, this is a strict rendering. Perhaps a different introductory verb would eliminate the ambiguity: *John offered to help Sean* (after all, the function of *let me* is offering to do something).

Comment: There's no ambiguity. If John actually wanted Sean to help *him*, he'd hardly tell Sean to *let himself help John*, would he? It's just clumsy because the second "him" is effectively redundant - discard it, and everything's fine.

Comment: That's very true.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> John told Sean that he should let John help him.

It gets a bit complicated because there are two singular males, but otherwise it is fairly straightforward. Other ways of rendering the imperative in indirect speech could be chosen instead, like "must"; or the entire "let" construction could be done away with in a less literal version:

> John told Sean that he would help him.

Comment: Doesn't the meaning change in the first sentence you suggest? **John** is supposed to do the helping, while **Sean** will let **John** help him, right?

Comment: @Irene: Oops! You're right, that was the opposite of the intended meaning. Corrected.

Comment: Per my comment to Barrie's answer, I really think OP is just trying to steer people towards a clumsy contrived construction - it might occur in speech, but in writing anyone should have enough time to just drop the second "him". *"John told Sean to let him help"*. Problem solved.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Sure, agreed. It's not really reported speech, but it is better.

Answer (score 0):

The indirect speech of John told Sean "Let me help you" will be "John told Sean that he would help him."

Good luck for your exams .

Comment: Really?  It seems to me to be saying something quite different, because you've dropped "let".  If you asked me to give the "direct" version of "John told Sean that he would help him", I would have said "John told Sean 'I will help you'".  And to answer the OP's question, it would have to be "John told Sean to let him help him", which is an absolutely terrible sentence, due to the potential confusion over which "him" refers to which character.

Comment: @David Wallace: It's a bit disingenuous of OP to mix "told" and "let" in the first place. Accept "told", and you should get *""John told Sean he would help""*. But accept "let", and you should get *"John asked Sean to let him help"*.